# Convert a spark structured streaming dataframe into JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a stream using spark structured streaming that has the structure:

```
col1
col2
col3
```

After some transformations I want to write the dataframe to the console in json format. I am trying the following approach:

```
df.select(to_json($"*"))
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()
```

But I get `Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'structstojson';`

Is there a way to join all rows into the same column in order to be able to use `to_json`?

The expected output is a dataframe with one column that has json data on each row:

```
{"col1":"val11","col2":"val12","col3":"val13"}
{"col1":"val21","col2":"val22","col3":"val23"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`to_json` has the following defintions :

```
def to_json(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
def to_json(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,options: java.util.Map[String,String]): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
def to_json(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,options: Map[String,String]): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Here's our dataframe :

```
df.show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
+----+----+----+
```

You need to create a `struct` and then call `to_json` on it. Something like :

```
df.select(to_json( struct( df.columns.map(col(_)):_*  ) )  as "json").show(false)
+----------------------------------+
|json                              |
+----------------------------------+
|{"col1":"a","col2":"b","col3":"c"}|
|{"col1":"d","col2":"e","col3":"f"}|
+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more direct approach:

```
df.toJSON.writeStream
    .queryName("aakriti")
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("numRows", "1000")
    .option("truncate", false)
    .start();
```