# Passing variable number of parameters to pyspark.sql.functions.udf

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am creating a spark structured streaming application using pyspark and want to output the data as json packet for every single row. I am doing it using udf as given below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

1 def create_json_packet(when, ip, mac):
2     json_dict = {
3        'When': when.timestamp(),
4        'IP': ip,
5        'MAC': mac
6    }
7    return json.dumps(json_dict)

8 def construct_output_packet(data_frame)
9      json_udf = udf(create_json_packet, StringType())
10     out_df = data_frame.select(json_udf(data_frame.when, data_frame.ip, data_frame.mac)).alias("output_json"))
11     return out_df
```

This is working fine and I am getting a nice formatted JSON the way I wanted as shown below

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|output_json                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"When": 1704204003.0, "IP": "10.14.6.11", "MAC": "3C:A3:08:4D:91:71"}  |
|{"When": 1704204003.0, "IP": "10.18.11.98", "MAC": "02:3F:3B:94:8F:E0"} |
|{"When": 1704204003.0, "IP": "10.13.21.51", "MAC": "F0:3C:07:95:34:C5"} |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the problem is the `data_frame` at Line # 10 has more than 20 columns and I don't want to expand all those manually and update `create_json_packet` which inputs 20 number of parameters. Is there any way I can use some kind of list / compact for loop and `**kwargs` to achieve this in a way that column names in `data_frame` becomes `keys` of `**kwargs` which I can use to generate the json object.

Comment: Why do you need a udf? Is built-in [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_json) not sufficient?

Comment: To the best of my understanding to_json returns a string, I have to reconstruct back a DataFrame so that I can output to kafka DataStreamWriter. I need some extra time how I would be able to do this in a clean way. Due to time I have I am doing it the way I already know using udf. I did found a post which does this in scala though. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907488/convert-a-spark-structured-streaming-dataframe-into-json

Comment: `output_json`, in your example, is also a string. the UDF you've created has the return type as `StringType()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of columns which you want to include in the `dict` and pass it to the `udf` in `withColumn`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import json

# Sample data
data = [
    ("2022-01-01", "192.168.1.1", "00:1A:2B:3C:4D:5E"),
    ("2022-01-02", "192.168.1.2", "11:22:33:44:55:66"),
    # Add more rows with similar structure
]

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
columns = ["when", "ip", "mac"]

# Create the DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Define a UDF to create a dictionary from variable parameters
@udf(StringType())
def create_json_packet(*args):
    subset_dict = dict(zip(subset_columns, args))
    return json.dumps(subset_dict)


# Specify the subset of columns you want to include in the dictionary
subset_columns = ["when", "ip"]

df \
.withColumn("output_json", create_json_packet(*subset_columns)) \
.show(10, truncate=False)

Output:
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|when      |ip         |mac              |output_json                                |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|2022-01-01|192.168.1.1|00:1A:2B:3C:4D:5E|{"when": "2022-01-01", "ip": "192.168.1.1"}|
|2022-01-02|192.168.1.2|11:22:33:44:55:66|{"when": "2022-01-02", "ip": "192.168.1.2"}|
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Or if you want, you can also pass `subset_columns` array to `udf` as a parameter:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# Define a UDF to create a dictionary from variable parameters
@udf(StringType())
def create_json_packet(subset_columns, *args):
    subset_dict = dict(zip(subset_columns, args))
    return json.dumps(subset_dict)

df \
.withColumn("output_json", create_json_packet(lit(subset_columns), *subset_columns)) \
.show(10, truncate=False)
```